# Can't install Arial.ttf from Windows / Arial is "Arial Narrow"

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, fontconfig, ttf

I use Arch Linux, and have followed the wiki pages regarding [Fonts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts), [Font configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration), [Microsoft fonts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microsoft_fonts) and [Infinality](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Infinality).

However, it seems something is wrong with the Microsoft fonts. I copied them over from a mounted **Windows 10** installation. I first copied the fonts from `C:\Windows\Fonts` to another place (in Windows), as `cp` was giving me `unsupported reparse point` errors on a lot of files.

I counted the number of files, there were more than 300. Using `fc-cache -rv`, only **217** fonts were detected.

The problem is most noticable to me as `Arial` resolves to `Arial Narrow`. That looks like crap:

[image: Arial narrow]

I checked all my font config files thrice, there are no rules that substitute Arial with Arial Narrow.

The Arial.TTF font is simply not installed: `fc-list |  grep -i 'arial' | cut -d':' -f 2,3`:

```
/usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts/ARIALN.TTF: Arial,Arial Narrow
/usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts/ARIALNB.TTF: Arial,Arial Narrow
/usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts/ARIALNI.TTF: Arial,Arial Narrow
/usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts/ARIALNBI.TTF: Arial,Arial Narrow
/usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts/ARLRDBD.TTF: Arial Rounded MT Bold
/usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts/ARIALUNI.TTF: Arial Unicode MS
```

`fc-match arial`:

```
ARIALN.TTF: "Arial" "Narrow"
```

I managed to do it in the past with **Windows 8**. Could that be the reason (Windows 10 now)?

## Update

It gets even more crazy. I've copied fonts from Windows 8 now and rebuilt the cache. Arial appears to be installed and works in a few applications **except Firefox**. It renders Arial as completely blank!

Answer (score 3):

The problem turned out to be related to permissions. You need to run `fc-cache` in **non-root** mode to use fonts in (some?) applications.

This in turn requires the font files to have proper permissions, or else `fc-cache` (silently) skips them:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts
```

Notice the very crucial `-R` switch. You need to set the permissions on the files themselves! That was what I was missing.

<s>Going to try again now using Windows 10 fonts.</s> Works with Windows 10 fonts too!

Comment: Maybe some part of the problem related to the permission. But I still found some fonts cannot be recognized because some ttf in  System/windows/Fonts/ in the Windows are links , and they link to some place, Linux cannot found. When you copy all the otf to linux , just copy the link.

Comment: @einverne initially I found that out as well, but the solution is to first copy them over to another place, using Windows itself. Open the directory in Explorer, ctrl+A and ctrl+C, and paste them somewhere else. Then copy them to linux.

Comment: yeah, I think this is the solution. I did it just now, and don't have the problem now.